# Simple test tool for python projects

Tags: python, unit-testing, excel, testing

I have a python project that takes in two Excel spreadsheets with various data as input, and depending on given parameters in a python 'run' type module, produces several spreadsheets which contain statistical information as outputs.  I have several versions of this project released already to a few clients, but testing to make sure that the input spreadsheets, their parameters (in a python module), and their corresponding output spreadsheets are the same is very time consuming because I have a lot of possible parameters that can be used.  Is there a tool or something I can do or use to automate testing for my project to ensure inputs, parameters and outputs of past versions of the project match the latest version?

I know that there are many testing modules in python (in particular unittest, nose, Scons, doctest etc), but I was wondering if anyone knew of a simpler tool for testing inputs and outputs, or a way to create my own quickly.  I do not want to test every single method due to time and cost constraints and complexity of the project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One of the unit testing frameworks you list is just what you need. Testing is hard and takes time. If you try to do it without putting in sufficient time and thought your testing won't be worth very much.

It sounds like you are wanting a list of inputs and outputs that your test loops through. That's easy. Just declare such a list in your test case and run a loop across it. That's the easy bit. The hard bit is working out the test data.